# Corrupted H.264 file: NAL unit header mystery

Tags: video, streaming, h.264

I've been examining a corrupted H.264 stream, which is composed of NAL units. It is indicated, that the type of corruption is regarding IDR Picture, so the nal_unit_type of value 5 should be present. I've successfully identified the start of NAL units using the sequences `0x00 00 00 01` or `0x00 00 01`, followed by a header consisting of `nal_ref_idc` and `nal_unit_type`.

However, my search for corrupt NAL units has left me puzzled. The only headers I've found are `67`, `68`, `01`, `41`, and none of them seem to indicate a corrupt NAL unit. I've searched the internet for examples of corrupt NAL units without success.

Am I misunderstanding how NAL units work, or is there a specific header pattern for corrupt units?

To provide some context, here's the beginning of the H.264 stream:

Any insights or examples of corrupt NAL units would be greatly appreciated, as it would help me with understanding it.

```
00 00 00 01 67 64 00 32 AC D9 80 78 02 27 E5 C0 5A 80 80 80 A0 00 00 7D 20 00 1D 4C 01 E3 06 33 40 00 00 00 01 68 E9 78 F2 C8 B0 00 00 01 06 05 FF FF AB DC 45 E9 BD E6 D9 48 B7 96 2C D8 20 D9 23 EE EF 78 32 36 34 20 2D 20 63 6F 72 65 20 31 36 33 20 72 33 30 36 30 20 35 64 62 36 61 61 36
```

Comment: You say _"It is indicated, that the type of corruption is regarding IDR Picture, so the `nal_unit_type` of value 5 should be present."_ Who (or what) is indicating that there is corruption? You say _"...value of 5 should be present"_ Is that your own expectation or you were told that the video is corrupt because it has no IDR picture? IDR is typically found as a byte value of `25` or `45` or `65` (where the type would be in that digit of 5). If you are only finding picture NALUs of byte `01` and `41` then your video won't play well. After finding metadata `67`, `68`, `06` what NALU comes next?

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstanding.
Normally the H.264 stream (or file) is not self-aware. So it doesn't know about it's own corruption.
I am guessing that you are trying to decode the stream and that you are getting an error message.
Please share your H.264 file, the decoder that you are using and the error message.

A common corruption that I see is a truncation.
So if you want a corrupted IDR frame look for 00 00 01 x5 - jump to the end of the IDR NAL and set some bytes to 0x00 and see how you decoder reacts.

Comment: As part of a university exercise, I been given a h264 byte stream, which I should convert to a mp4, then as an answer, read the code from the video. The h264 is corrupt and I have to repair it. 

A hint was given, that 4 NALU's have an invalid value regarding nal_unit_type. Also the type of corruption points towards issues with IDR pictures.

I have writen a script, which reads out all the header after the prefixes for every NALU, but like I mentioned in my question, none of them points towards a faulty NALU. I am puzzled to were the issues in the NALU is.

Comment: @josef Can you tell us what NALU comes next, after your shown bytes? You could show the NALU's sequence of `[one byte before] + [start code bytes] + [next 5 bytes after]` for a faster answer. The so-called corruption could be anything from... the first IDR is disguised as a P/B frame _eg:_ byte `41`, or maybe the NALU byte `01` you found after the start codes should be changed into a `65` to use it as an IDR. Also consider that "corruption" could mean an IDR header byte is missing (_eg:_ after start code it skips header and leads straight into macroblock data). Good luck I hope you solve it.